# How can the injectivity of $f$ imply that $b$ is not in the image of the boundary of $Q$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

In the book of *Analysis on Manifolds* by Munkres, at page 65, it is given that

**For $B = f(A)$,**
[image]

The author mentions the Brouwer theorem of invariance of domain in the next chapter, but I cannot understand how the injectivity of $f$ implies that $b$ is not in the image of the boundary of $Q$.

Comment: @freakish I'm may not be remembering correctly, but are continuos functions maps interior to interior, and boundary to boundary ?

Comment: No, but by the asumption the interior of $Q$ contains $a$ (the first sentence of the second paragraph). Therefore no point from boundary (being disjoint with interior) can be mapped to $b=f(a)$ by injectivity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(\partial Q)$ is not disjoint from $b$ then $f(c)=b$ for some $c\in\partial Q$.

But we also have $f(a)=b$ so the injectivity of $f$ then leads to $a=c\in\partial Q$ contradicting that $a$ is an element of the interior of $Q$.

Comment: But $A$ is open, so $\partial A \not \subseteq A$.

Comment: What is the relevance of that for my answer?

Comment: Sorry, I'm little distracted.

Comment: @onurcanbektas Let's make it: "$f(\text{comment on my answer})$ is disjoint from $b:=\text{my answer}$ then ;-). You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

If $b\in f(\operatorname{Bd}Q)$, then $b=f(x)$ for some $x\in\operatorname{Bd}Q$ and so (since $f$ injective) $a(=f^{-1}(b))\in\operatorname{Bd}Q$. But this is not true.

Comment: But $A$ is open, so $\partial A \not \subseteq A$.

Comment: @onurcanbektas What has this to do with what I wrote? I did not mention $A$.

Comment: I'm little distracted, sorry. you are right.